# Is this algorithm adequate for 2016 ICPC World Finals task L?

Tags: algorithm

I've been asked to program a solution for the 2016 ICPC World Finals problem L, as a homework.

I've managed to successfully create and run a program that solves the problem in question. However, I'm curious if there is a better algorithm for solving the problem.

Problem L is as follows:

> A set of `n` hard drives needs to be reformatted. When drive `i` is reformatted, its capacity will go from `a_i` GB to `b_i` GB. All the hard drives are initially full to brim. In order to store the data from hard drive `x` while
>   it is being reformatted, you are allowed to buy an extra hard drive.
>   Any drive that has been reformatted can be used to store more data
>   (assuming it has the capacity to do so). The data from hard drive `x`
>   can be split among other hard drives. Write a program that estimates
>   the minimum amount of extra space required in order to reformat the
>   hard drives without losing data.

The algorithm I'm currently using is the same one as in [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJtR7bFC8MU).

The algorithm follows these steps:

1. Separate the hard drives that lose capacity upon being reformatted from those that maintain or increase their capacity upon being reformatted.
2. Sort the new lists by initial capacity of the hard drives. The ones that lose capacity (called "shrink list") are sorted from biggest to smallest, and the others (called "grow list") are sorted from smallest to biggest.
3. Starting with the first member of the grow list, check its starting capacity and assign that value to *swap* (the accumulated required space for successfully swapping around the data).
4. After reformatting the hard drive, assign to *extra* the amount of capacity gained from reformatting the first hard drive (this first value will always be at least 0).
5. Compare the initial capacity of the next hard drive (hard drive `x`) that is going to be reformatted, with the values of *swap* + *extra*. If *swap* + *extra* is at least equal to the initial value of hard drive `x` then the hard drive can be reformatted.
6. If the value of *swap* + *extra* is smaller than the initial capacity of hard drive `x`, increase the value of *swap* until you have enough capacity to make the swap, and reformat drive `x`.
7. Add to *extra* the difference between the final and initial capacities of hard drive `x`, even if it's a negative value.
8. Return to step 5 until all members of the grow list are reformatted.
9. Once all members of the grow list have been reformatted, return to step 5, but now, use the shrink list instead.

Is there is a better/faster way to solve this problem?

Comment: https://icpc.baylor.edu/worldfinals/problems has a list of judge data (inputs and outputs) for all problems, as well as solutions for 2017-2018 (doesn't help for your 2016 problem). If you can run your solution on the largest inputs and produce the correct output within the time limit, then I suppose there isn't anything much better you can do (within the scope of a contest, e.g., no parallelism etc.).